# Permutations in R

Tags: r

how can R generate permutations as follows:

- numbers to be used are 1, 2, 5 and 10
- combination should be based on 2 numbers
- order of the combinations is not important

for the above, this results in:

```
1- 1, 2
2- 1, 5
3- 1, 10
4- 2, 5 
5- 2, 10
6- 5, 10
```

Comment: that are combinations 2 from 4 (not permutations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `combn` :

```
combn(c(1,2,5,10),2) # before the comma is your values to be used, after is the number of elements to be chosen
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    2    2    5
[2,]    2    5   10    5   10   10
```

Comment: @patfee if you're happy, please accept etiennes answer. Keeps others from spending time on your question.